# \Cref does not recognize the second figure reference, problem with package ordering?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

Part of my code is like:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}


\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{}


\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing


\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {pictures/} }
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}




\date{}


\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}


\newpage


The TPR and TNR are summarized in Table and plotted in Figures (\Cref{figboxUsensi, figboxUspeci}).





\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{boxplot Usensi nw15.png} 
\caption{Boxplot of TPR on $\mathbf{u}$ dimension for nw15} \label{fig:boxUsensinw15}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Boxplot of TPR on $\mathbf{u}$ dimension for nw1, nw10 and nw15.}
\label{figboxUsensi}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{boxplot Uspeci nw15.png} 
\caption{Boxplot of TNR on $\mathbf{u}$ dimension for nw15} \label{fig:boxUspecinw15}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Boxplot of TNR on $\mathbf{u}$ dimension for nw1, nw10 and nw15.}
\label{figboxUspeci}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

But I got this:

> The TPR and TNR are summarized in Table and plotted in Figures (Figure
>   1 and ??).

Is this the problem with packages ordering? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your document is incomplete (no `\documentclass`) and there is not a single `\caption` nor `\label` statement, so there's nothing to refer. Please post the minimal version of your document that produces the output you provided

Comment: It's by far not minimal, but the error is the space after `,` in the `\Cref` command: `\Cref{figboxUsensi, figboxUspeci}` looks for a label named like " figboxUspeci" , not "figboxUspeci"

Comment: Thanks Christian, the problem is indeed the extra space! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'usual' error or typo when using label names with `\ref` or `\cref` is that a space character actually is important (or better, it is important to remove it there)

`\Cref{figboxUsensi, figboxUspeci}` will look after a label named (without quotes, however)

> " figboxUspeci"

and not

> "figboxUspeci"

Don't use space characters before or after a label name with `\ref` or `\cref` etc. commands.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}


\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{}


\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing


\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {pictures/} }
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}




\date{}


\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}


\newpage


The TPR and TNR are summarized in Table and plotted in Figures (\Cref{figboxUsensi, figboxUspeci}).





\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{boxplot Usensi nw1.png} 
\caption{Boxplot of TPR on $\mathbf{u}$ dimension for nw1} \label{fig:boxUsensinw1}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{3 ex}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{boxplot Usensi nw10.png} 
\caption{Boxplot of TPR on $\mathbf{u}$ dimension for nw10} \label{fig:boxUsensinw10}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{3 ex}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{boxplot Usensi nw15.png} 
\caption{Boxplot of TPR on $\mathbf{u}$ dimension for nw15} \label{fig:boxUsensinw15}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Boxplot of TPR on $\mathbf{u}$ dimension for nw1, nw10 and nw15.}
\label{figboxUsensi}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{boxplot Uspeci nw1.png} 
\caption{Boxplot of TNR on $\mathbf{u}$ dimension for nw1} \label{fig:boxUspecinw1}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{3 ex}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{boxplot Uspeci nw10.png} 
\caption{Boxplot of TNR on $\mathbf{u}$ dimension for nw10} \label{fig:boxUspecinw10}
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{3 ex}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{boxplot Uspeci nw15.png} 
\caption{Boxplot of TNR on $\mathbf{u}$ dimension for nw15} \label{fig:boxUspecinw15}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Boxplot of TNR on $\mathbf{u}$ dimension for nw1, nw10 and nw15.}
\label{figboxUspeci}
\end{figure}





\end{document}
```

Comment: @user348472: Please accept my solution then to mark it as solved!